# bootstrap glyphicons inside asp:buttons disapear after gridview sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, glyphicons

What should I do to fix this? html inside a asp:button need a fix to be displayed, I use this method (it works unless I do click on the header of any column to sort the gridview):

```
private void FixGlyph(PlaceHolder ph, Button btn, string iconClass, string customLabelStye = "")
    {
        if (btn.Visible)
        {
            var g = new HtmlGenericControl();
            g.ID = "labelFor_" + btn.ID;
            g.TagName = "label";
            g.Attributes.Add("for", btn.ClientID);
            g.Attributes.Add("class", "" + btn.CssClass + "");
            if (customLabelStye != "")
            {
                g.Attributes.Add("style", customLabelStye);
            }
            g.InnerHtml = "<i class='" + iconClass + "'></i> " + btn.Text;
            ph.Controls.Add(g);
            btn.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;");
        }
    }
```

my gridview is this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataKeyNames="FICHA" runat="server" GridLines="None" OnSorted="GridViewFix" AllowSorting="true" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" ShowFooter="true" PagerStyle-CssClass="bs-pagination text-center">
            <Columns>
                    <%-- Ficha del empleado --%>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ficha" SortExpression="FICHA">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFicha" Text='<%# Eval("FICHA") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                            <%-- columna de eliminar --%>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>">
                        <ItemStyle Width="20" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="delPh" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <asp:Button ID="delBtn" CssClass="btn btn-link " data-toggle="modal" ToolTip="Modify" data-target="#deleteModal" runat="server" autopostback="false" OnClick="delBtn_Click" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate> 
    <Triggers>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

my Page_Load is like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            Button dbtn = row.FindControl("delBtn") as Button;
            PlaceHolder dPH = row.FindControl("delPh") as PlaceHolder;
            FixGlyph(dPH, dbtn, "glyphicon glyphicon-remove", "padding:0 !important;");
        }
    }
```

and I even tried to use onSorted event for the gridview:

```
protected void GridViewFix(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            Button dbtn = row.FindControl("delBtn") as Button;
            PlaceHolder dPH = row.FindControl("delPh") as PlaceHolder;
            FixGlyph(dPH, dbtn, "glyphicon glyphicon-remove", "padding:0 !important;");
        }
    }
```

which gets trigged, aparently finds the controls and fix the labels but... then something happend after GridViewFix and reloads the components, again without the glyphicons

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are doing this in code? It seems like you could add one tiny bit of markup and remove ALL the code your have posted.

Comment: Hello Ben first I need glyphicons , they don't apear if you use it inside asp:button, I need asp:button for whole other reasons. yes i could use asp:Linkbutton  but then code behind won't work

Comment: You seem to be dynamically adding a `<label<i></i><label>` for the glyph icons. I can see no reason why you are doing this in code, just add it to the markup. Also there is nothing that you can do with an `asp:Button` that you can't do with a `asp:LinkButton`.

Comment: you'r right.. already found a solution  check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the question wasn't completly clear.. buttons have data-toggle and data-target atributes which LinkButtons don't and that's why  wanted them so bad. I Needed to open a modal at the same time I triggered an event on code behind. so this fix the issue: Just trigger the modal yourself with javascript.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="AddAreaBtn" runat="server" autopostback="false" OnClientClick="javascript:$('#BorrarAreaModal').modal('show');" OnClick="BorraArea_Click">
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put your code to add the glyphs in the Page_PreRender method. It's possible that after page_load the Gridview has an event that is firing and recreating the button controls.